# Tkinter title with line around area

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, title

So in tkinter I'm making a program, I want to know can you make a title box thing like the one in this image with the title "Booking Details"?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a [Label Frame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm).

> The LabelFrame widget is a variant of the Tkinter Frame widget. By default, it draws a border around its child widgets, and it can also display a title.

Comment: Do you know how I would achieve adding in a separator like the title "Availability" in the image?